# ЗАПРОС ДО PHP SERVER

Tags: ajax

Подскажите, розширение PHP SERVER ДЛЯ VS CODE ЖЕ НЕ ПОЗВОЛЯЕТ НОРМАЛЬНО ПЕРЕДАВАТЬ ДАННЫЕ ЧЕРЕЗ ЗАПРОСЫ НА СЕРВЕР, ДЛЯ ЭТОГО НУЖНО СКАЧИВАТЬ XAMPP?